# ASP.NET URL redirection

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect

I want, when I type `http://localhost/Admin`, to take me to the page `http://localhost/Something/Login.aspx`. How can I do this?

Comment: do you want the person to login to a protected area on your website or do you only want a redirect? Please clarify.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you want the user to be logged in to be able to access certain pages? Or do you simply want to perform a redirect? WebForms or MVC?

Comment: I only want to make a redirect to a specific URL.

Comment: `Response.Redirect("~/Something/Login.aspx")` should do the trick then

Comment: I don't want to redirect form code behind (C#). I want to rewrite the URL http://localhost/Admin into http://localhost/Something/Login.aspx.

Comment: What is supposed to happen after the user has logged in? are they then allowed to view pages under /Admin/ or should they stay in /Something/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx). A very short introduction follows.

You need to create a login page that makes a call like this, after verifying the identity of the user:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName);
```

Then you need to wire up the login page in the `web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Something/Login.aspx" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Furthermore, you will need to tell the framework that all URLs below `~/Admin/` requires the user to be authenticaticated. This can be done by adding an another `web.config` file within that folder:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Read the article linked above, or search the web for "ASP.NET forms authentication" and you will soon be on the right track.

---

**EDIT 1** - If all you want to do is really to "make a redirect to a specific URL", then this is sufficient:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Something/Login.aspx")
```

From the URLs you mention in the your questions, it seems that you are trying to enforce some kind of authentication/authorization scheme. If this is true, forms authentication is a better answer.

---

**EDIT 2** - If you want to *rewrite*, not redirect, requests from `~/Admin` to `~/Something/Login.aspx` you can do so by mapping a URL mapping in your root `web.config` file

```
<system.web>
    <urlMappings>
        <add url="~/Admin/Default.aspx" mappedUrl="~/Something/Login.aspx"/>
    </urlMappings>
</system.web>
```

In most setups, the web server will only pass the request to ASP.NET if the requested URL ends with a known suffix, such as `.aspx`. On approach to trick the web server to pass requests for `~/Admin` to ASP.NET, is to use the "default document" feature in the web server. For this to work, you must add an empty file named `Default.aspx` in the `~/Admin` folder.